# Выход из программы при невыполнении условия if

Tags: java, break

Пытаюсь добиться того, чтобы после введения пустого имени или отрицательного возраста не только на экране отображалась ошибка, но и прерывалась программа. Пробовала писать слова `break` после текста ошибки, но выдается сообщение, что `break` не может быть вне цикла. Что можно сделать?

```java
public class xxx {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Cat cat1 = new Cat();
        cat1.setName("Kitty");
        cat1.setAge(5);
        System.out.println(cat1.getName() + ", " + cat1.getAge());
        Cat cat2 = new Cat();
        cat2.setName("");
        cat2.setAge(7);
        System.out.println(cat2.getName() + ", " + cat2.getAge());
    }

    public static class Cat {
        private String name;
        private int age;

        public void setName(String name) {
            if (name.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("Don't enter an empty name!");
            } else
                this.name = name;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setAge(int age) {
            if (age < 0) {
                System.out.println("Enter correct age, please!");
            } else
                this.age = age;
        }

        public int getAge() {
            return age;
        }
    }
}
```

В консоли выводится:

```
Kitty, 5
Don't enter an empty name!
null, 7
```

Comment: Думаю не совсем будет правильно завершать программу, лучше уже засунуть все в цикл и не выходить с него пока значения для объектов не удовлетворят ваших ожиданий

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`System.exit(0)` завершит программу с кодом 0. Если вы хотите сообщить ошибке сделай `System.exit(1)`

Answer (score 0):

При возникновении ошибки лучше кидать (`throw`) `Exception`.

При этом ответственность кидающего кода только в том, чтобы прекратить работу и сообщить.

Обычный код не знает о существовании `System.out` (может у нас сервер) и не имеет права выходить из программы.

Код, который отвечает за программу (например в main) делает `try...catch`, и уже в `catch` может решить сделать `print` и `exit`.

Mожно создать свои типы ошибок, отнаследованные от `Exception`.